# Using JavaScript with form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to simply pull an input from an html form and manipulate it with JavaScript. When I console.log the variable I created in JavaScript I am just getting my html element back. If I attempt to add [0] or .value, I get undefined and a JQuery error, respectively. I am at a loss as to the reason this isn't working. If it matters I am doing all this in CodePen.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <form id="myForm">
  Construction Year: <br>
  <input type="text" id="construction_field" name="construction_field" value=""><br>
  </form>
  <button onclick="myFunction">Find P</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  function myFunction () {
  var constructionYear = document.getElementById("construction_field");
  console.log(constructionYear);
  }
});
```

I apologize for such a simple question, but I can't find an answer that works to save my life. If it isn't obvious I am very new and struggling, any examples would be amazing.

Comment: Works just fine with `.value` http://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/zZJLLr?editors=1111

Comment: `[0]` would fail because getElementById doesn't return an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use jQuery:

```
var constructionYear = jQuery('#construction_field').val();
```

If you wish to use vanilla JavaScript:

```
var constructionYear = document.getElementById('construction_field').value;
```

Comment: I think you were right about value. After reworking the code you answer worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use console.log(constructionYear.value);

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm pretty sure the value was the issue. I accidentally deleted some code and when I rewrote it with value it worked!

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, please upvote/accept. Thanks.